# Ubuntu 17.04 running off live DVD gives "can’t open /dev/sr0: No medium found" error

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, 17.04, livedvd

I have a 14 year old computer that I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 on .
I was trying to get the Desktop remix -Gnome release running from the DVD for Ubuntu 17.04 that came with issue 225 of the Linux format magazine

When I select another distribution (“Solus”) from the DVD it starts up fine and I can use it off the live DVD..

However when I run the Ubuntu-Desktop-remix-Gnome. It gets past an ntermediate stage (Interlocking blue U icon) and then puts the message posted below on tty 1.

I know the latter part of the message ( about disk errors or unplugging active drives etc) is not applicable to me since I am running this off my built in DVDROM. 
I know the media does indeed have the /UbuntuRemix/ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso on it.
Although I didn’t check the md5sum when I burnt the DVD , I can get the downloaded iso to boot on different hardware from a USB stick.

Any idea how to get around the “No medium found error”

￼

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-19ubuntu2) built in shell (ash)
Enter ‘help’ for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) stdin: Not a typewriter
/scripts/casper-premount/20iso_scan: line 46: can’t open /dev/sr0: No medium found

Could not find the ISO /UbuntuRemix/ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso
This could also happen if the file system is not clean because of an operating system crash, an interrupted boot process, an improper shutdown, or unplugging of a removable device without first unmounting or ejecting it. To fix this, simply reboot into Windows, let it fully start, log in , run ‘chkdsk /r’, then gracefully shutdown and reboot back into Windows. After this you should be able to reboot again and resume the installation.
```

Comment: Is your DVD drive really recognized as /dev/sr0? Maybe it's hard-coded in the loader...

Comment: I dont know how to tell what my DVD drive is recognized as ...at least from the (initramfs) prompt.